# Android ActionBar Compat Tabs with swipeable views change icons action bar to change fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, swipe, android-actionbar-compat

you can do this:
ActionBar Compat Tabs with swipeable views change icons action bar to change fragment

Now:
Not show icons in action bar to change Tab's

Example:

ActionBar
TAB1|TAB2|TAB3
FRAGMENT

TAB1--ActionBar (add, save)|||TAB2-- ActionBar (empty)|||TAB3-- ActionBar (add)

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every fragment you should add such methods as:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.you_menu_file, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuitem1:
            //your implementation of menu item click
            break;
        case R.id.menuitem2:
            //your implementation of menu item click
            break;
        case R.id.menuitem3:
            //your implementation of menu item click
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have:                                                       Fragment TAB1                                                        onCreateView => setHasOptionsMenu(true);                  onCreateOptionsMenu =>getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate (R.menu.menu_tab1,menu);                                            onOptionsItemSelected => equalabove

Comment: do you have menu items in xml layout like in code below?             <item
 android:id="@+id/menu_add"
 android:title="add">
</item>

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have found the solution.the problem was within onOptionsItemSelected MainActivity must be "return false".now change the icons of the action bar to pass the fragments

Comment: Yes, that is what I wrote you, so you could mark answer as correct